# Android - URL Encoder not properly working

Tags: java, android, url

My URL String has two parts, first one is

```
http://abcabc.com/xyz/mmm/lorum/
```

Second is "abc def ghi", Here for last part I use

```
URLEncoder.encode("abc def ghi","utf-8");
```

This returns me "abc+def+ghi"

Final URL becomes

```
http://abcabc.com/xyz/mmm/lorum/abc+def+ghi
```

Which is wrong, It should be

```
http://abcabc.com/xyz/mmm/lorum/abc%20def%20ghi
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: `URLEncoder` uses `+` to replace spaces and not `%20`. This won't cause problems. See the docs...http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLEncoder.html

Comment: why do you say "it is wrong"?

Comment: Its not working, I am fetching json via web service. When I manually removes spaces and enter %20 instead, then it works fine. but not for replacing spaces with +

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Url_encoding#The_application.2Fx-www-form-urlencoded_type):

> When data that has been entered into HTML forms is submitted, the form field names and values are encoded and sent to the server in an HTTP request message using method GET or POST, or, historically, via email.[2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html) The encoding used by default is based on a very early version of the general URI percent-encoding rules, with a number of modifications such as newline normalization and replacing spaces with "+" instead of "%20"

So + is a valid way of encoding a space.

BTW, this is clearly [documented](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html):

> Utility class for HTML form encoding. This class contains static methods for converting a String to the application/x-www-form-urlencoded MIME format
>
> [...]
>
> The space character " " is converted into a plus sign "+".